# Angular not finding variable made by ng-repeat

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I am using an AngularDart component in my webpage with the `@Component`. I can access variables inside the class by using the standard angular expressions in the html by using `ng-model` and `{{}}`. However when implementing a standard looping procedure:

```
<div ng-repeat="(x, y) in example_dictionary" ng-if="example_dictionary!=null">
    {{x}}
</div>
```

This snippet gives me the strange error `Class '~~~' has no instance getter 'x'` (Class name snipped). The error is not wrong per-say. The class really does not contain any getter of `x`, but it shouldn't need to because the `ng-repeat` method is setting it and maintaining it.

For added entertainment, I replaced the `{{x}}` section with a static string `I am looping` and behold the loop command does in fact loop through the dictionary the proper amount. So the `ng-repeat` is not causing any problems with either looping or setting both of the non-pre-existing `x` and `y` variables.

**The question:** Why can't I access `x` and how can I access `x`?

Answer (score 0):

That should work, but have you tried?

```
<div ng-repeat="entry in example_dictionary">
    {{entry.x}}
</div>
```

Comment: By performing the above, the code now provides `Class '~~~' has no instance getter 'entry'`. Thanks for the quick reply!

Answer (score 0):

After reducing the problem to a really simple size, I found out that removing the `ng-if` section of the div fixed the problem. How and why that even was a problem is beyond me. I now segregated the action of `ng-if` and `ng-repeat` into separate divs. I am not particularly happy with my findings, but it works.